# Springframework : PermittedSubclasses requires ASM8/9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, payara, jakarta-migration

I have updated the lib and dependency of my project including :

1. From OpenJDK 11 to OpenJDK 17.0.2
2. From JavaEE to Jakarta 9
3. From Springboot 2.7.4 to 3.0.1

The application can be built successfully, and I try to deploy it to Payara Server 6.2022.2 that running OpenJDK 17. However, the following errors are kept throwing and Spring cannot be started.

I have confirmed that the Springboot is the latest version and supports Java 17 environment. Is there any dependency missing?

My pom.xml :

> ```
> <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
> <parent>
>     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>     <version>3.0.1</version>
>     <relativePath/> 
> </parent>
> <version>1.0</version>
> <packaging>war</packaging>
>
> <properties>
>     <java.version>17</java.version>
>     <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
> </properties>
>
> <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
>
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
>         <exclusions>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>             </exclusion>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>             </exclusion>
>             <exclusion>
>                 <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
>             </exclusion>
>         </exclusions>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
>     </dependency>     
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>         <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
>         <version>9.0.0</version>
>         <type>jar</type>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

The content of module-info

> ```
> requires jakarta.jakartaee.api;
> requires spring.beans;
> requires spring.boot;
> requires spring.boot.loader;
> requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
> requires spring.context;
> requires spring.core;
> requires spring.security.config;
> requires spring.security.core;
> requires spring.security.web;
> requires spring.web;
> ```

The Application Class :

```
import com.xyz.web.application.resources.env;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; 
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication; 
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableConfigurationProperties(env.class)
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The log of Payara Server :

> SEVERE:   Exception while visiting
> org/springframework/beans/factory/aot/BeanRegistrationsAotContribution$Registration.class
> of size 2202 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Record requires
> ASM8  at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitRecordComponent(ClassVisitor.java:305)
> at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readRecordComponent(ClassReader.java:953)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:731)   at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)    at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)     at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> SEVERE:   Exception while visiting
> org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudPlatform.class of size 3703
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PermittedSubclasses requires
> ASM9  at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:266)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:706)   at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)    at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)     at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> SEVERE:   Exception while visiting
> org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigDataNotFoundAction.class
> of size 1750 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
> PermittedSubclasses requires ASM9     at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:266)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:706)   at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)    at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)     at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> SEVERE:   Exception while visiting
> org/springframework/boot/jdbc/DatabaseDriver.class of size 9179
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PermittedSubclasses requires
> ASM9  at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:266)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:706)   at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)    at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)     at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> SEVERE:   Exception while visiting
> org/springframework/boot/convert/DurationStyle.class of size 3821
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PermittedSubclasses requires
> ASM9  at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:266)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:706)   at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)    at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)     at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
>
> SEVERE:   Exception while visiting
> org/springframework/boot/convert/PeriodStyle.class of size 3986
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: PermittedSubclasses requires
> ASM9  at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitPermittedSubclass(ClassVisitor.java:266)
> at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:706)   at
> org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:424)    at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$5.on(Parser.java:336)     at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.handleEntry(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:164)
> at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.onSelectedEntries(ReadableArchiveScannerAdapter.java:130)
> at org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.doJob(Parser.java:321)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser.access$300(Parser.java:44)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:280)
> at
> org.glassfish.hk2.classmodel.reflect.Parser$3.call(Parser.java:269)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Comment: Do you have other dependency other than what mentioned in pom.xml?

Comment: I have updated the payara version to Payara Server 6.2023.5 and the spring can be started with OpenJDK 17.0.2

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar situation while building my Spring Boot 3 project from the command line using Gradle.  The solution that worked for me is to upgrade the version of Gradle.  I upgraded from 7.2 to 7.6 and that solved the ASM9 issue.

See the line starting with `distributionUrl` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`, located in `gradle/wrapper`:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had answered this already. Glassfish and Payara are using older versions of ASM and CDI. Until they upgrade their distributions, we're stuck migrating to Java 17 and Jakarta.

Comment: Which versions of ASM and CDI is GlassFish using, and which newer versions of both these two are available?

Comment: I upgrade to latest version of payara (the version released in May 2023) and it seem ok now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I saw a payara release notice that announced that the most recent version of Payara contained ASM 9. For me, thats 1/2 the battle cause SpringWebMvc still needs newer CDI installed as well. I'll pull down payara soon and try again....maybe they fixed CDI too but it wasn't in the release notice.